# Django SearchRank annotation not being assigned, bug in production but not dev

Tags: django, postgresql, search, annotations, django-queryset

My Django application (Apache/WSGI with Postgres backend) is running into an error in production which I can't reproduce in dev or by using the Django shell on the production machine. How can I debug this?

The application has a Story model

```
class Story(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    quality = models.FloatField(default=0)
    search = SearchVectorField(null=True)
```

with a signal to populate `search` on save:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Story) 
def update_search_vector(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   Story.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(search=SearchVector('title', 'content'))
```

When a user searches, I want to return relevant and high-quality results. I assign score as the harmonic mean of these two values:

```
query = SearchQuery(form.cleaned_data['query'])
stories = stories.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(F('search'), query),
    score=F('rank') * F('quality') / (F('rank') + F('quality'))
).filter(rank__gte=SEARCH_RANK_CUTOFF).order_by('-score')
```

This works fine in dev and on the Django shell in production. But when executed via the running app, the following error is raised: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rank' into field.`

I'm having trouble figuring out how to debug this. Could it be some kind of erroneous queryset caching?

Here's the full error traceback:

```
ERROR 2019-05-21 11:59:03,388 Internal Server Error: /stories
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/myapp/myapp/views.py", line 75, in browse
  score=F('rank') * F('quality') / (F('rank') + F('quality'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1056, in annotate
  clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1000, in add_annotation
  summarize=is_summary)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 446, in resolve_expression
  c.lhs = c.lhs.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 446, in resolve_expression
  c.lhs = c.lhs.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 511, in resolve_expression
  return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, simple_col)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1601, in resolve_ref
  join_info = self.setup_joins(field_list, self.get_meta(), self.get_initial_alias(), can_reuse=reuse)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1504, in setup_joins
  names[:pivot], opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
  "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rank' into field. Choices are: content, id, quality, search, title
```

I have the same dependency versions installed (via `requirements.txt`), but I am noticing that production is running python3.5.2 while dev is running 3.7.3. (And possibly `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` invokes another version?) This seems like a possible place to explore, but I don't understand how the annotation adding `rank` could fail without another exception.

Comment: SearchRank is only supported for postgres

Comment: The app uses Postgres in dev and production. The query works fine in the production shell.

Comment: post full error traceback

Comment: I experience the same issues on our production server. I can't replicate it on the dev server and I can't even replicate it locally with production settings and gunicorn.